# How does my professor come up with the recursive case in this algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, proof

My professor gave us the following explanation for the recursive algorithm for finding the permutations of a set of numbers:

---

[image]

---

When he has (T(m+1), n-1)) where does that come from? Why is it m+1 and n-1? I'm really confused as to where that comes from.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By the way - tell your professor that that permutation generator is inefficient. You can get `T(m, n) = nT(m + 1, n - 1)` fairly easily (I've got a few variations of such a generator floating around here somewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As he said, `m` represents the current size of `P` and `n` represents the size of `S`, in each recursive call you remove a number from `S` and add it to `P`, thus the size of your current permutation is increased by 1 (`m+1`) and the number of available numbers to add to the permutation is decreased by 1 (`n-1`)

Note that it is multiplied by `n` as you perform this action for each number in `S`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that part that says:

> Let `m` be the length of `P` and `n` be the size of `S`

And then in `printperm(P, S)`, you're calling `printperm((P,i), S-{i})`.

So, when recursing, we will add one element to `P`, and remove on element from `S`.

Thus `m` will increase by one and `n` will decrease by one, thus we get `T(m+1, n-1)`

I hope that helps.